# how preg_replace with $1 or \1 in replacement

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to use $1 in replacement.

```
$replacement = 'Some user content with $1';
$s = preg_replace('|#CONTENT#|', $replacement, 'Bla-bla #CONTENT#');
```

But I get
`Bla-bla Some content with` instead of `Bla-bla Some content with $1`

Comment: Try escaping the `\$1` The replacement will be `Bla-bla Some user content with $1`